# All Files Access Permission: Need to use Media Store API

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, google-play-services, google-play-console

I'm not using any **External read and write permission** in my app but still, Google reject my app. I have all mentioned all this but still getting rejected. and not give a proper solution from the Google support end.

https://prnt.sc/26f1xqs

https://prnt.sc/26f1ybn

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.shop">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />



<application

    android:label="shop"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
  
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         
            <data
                android:scheme="twittersdk"/> <!-- host is option -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaxxxx8bQWaxxxxxY4txxxD-0xxxxbjJk"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>



    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider[xxxxxxxx]"
        android:exported="false" />


    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />



</application>
```

I have already described the all thing about sensitive permission.

https://prnt.sc/26f239u

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Google reject my app.` Well tell why please.

Comment: `android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE` For what is this needed and do you need that?

Comment: READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE for getting gallery images and video.

Comment: Remove. The write too. Not needed.